# How to get full A1 notation of NamedRange?

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

How does a Java program get the full A1 notation of a Google Sheets `NamedRange`, including its `<sheetName>!` prefix?

To read a range of cells in a sheet, call `Spreadsheets.Values.get(String spreadsheetId, String range)` where `range` is in A1 notation. But when getting a range as a `NamedRange` there seems to be no way to get its sheet name (AKA sheet title) for prefixing in conversion to A1 notation.

It seems the only way supported by the API would be to get the NamedRange's embedded GridRange's sheetID with `NamedRange.getRange.getSheetId()`, then iterate through the spreadsheet's sheets with `Spreadsheet.getSheets()` until one sheet's getProperties().getSheetId() matches the GridRange's sheetID. But `NamedRange.getRange.getSheetId()` almost always returns `null` rather than the `gid=<sheetID>` from a sheet's URL. Indeed I don't understand why the call only intermittently returns the correct sheetID rather than returning `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the program again that contained the `NamedRange.getRange.getSheetId()` that was failing to reliably return a sheetID value (instead returning `null`). It had been returning `null` all day, after returning the correct sheetID once yesterday among otherwise `null`. And now it's reliably returning the sheetID.

The problem here looks like the Google Sheets API `Spreadsheets` webservice is intermittently failing, without any other sign, without any confession of such from Google. The Java API, especially for managing a `NamedRange`, seems to be so infrequently used if you google for people reporting even success using it that there's no mentions of it failing.

This is of course the worst kind of error. I can't even reproduce it now to report it to Google, which is often an exercise in futility anyway. I'll have to keep testing it until it fails reliably and then report it to Google, then wait forever to find out they're never fixing it.

---

The appended code fails. I commented the `getSheetId()` line that was failing but then started working OK.

```
private static String getRangeNameA1Str(String spreadsheetId, String rangeNameStr)
    throws IOException
{
    // Get spreadsheet by its ID.
    Spreadsheet spreadsheet = sheetsService.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId).execute();

    // Get named range.
    NamedRange namedRange =
        spreadsheet.getNamedRanges().parallelStream()
            .filter(aRange -> aRange.getName().equals(rangeNameStr))
            .findFirst()
            .get();

    // Get named range's GridRange for its A1 notation components.
    GridRange gridRange = namedRange.getRange();

    // Get named range's sheet's name.
    Integer  sheetID = gridRange.getSheetId(); // *** This call was getting null but then started getting the correct sheet ID.
    String sheetName =
        spreadsheet.getSheets().parallelStream()
            .filter(aSheet -> aSheet.getProperties().getSheetId().equals(sheetID))
            .findFirst()
            .get()
            .getProperties()
            .getTitle();

    // Get named range's A1 notation from its GridRange's components.
    String rangeA1Str =
        sheetName + "!" +
        Character.toString((char)((int)gridRange.getStartColumnIndex()+65)) +
        (gridRange.getStartRowIndex()+1) +
        ":" +
        Character.toString((char)((int)gridRange.getEndColumnIndex()+65)) +
        gridRange.getEndRowIndex();


    return(rangeA1Str);
} // getNamedRangeA1String
public static Sheets getSheetsService()
    throws IOException
{
    Credential credential = authorize();
    return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
    .build();
} // getSheetsService
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using that isn't the working?

Comment: Well, it started working again. And then other GS API code that was working stopped working, just getting the spreadsheet from the service, now returning a `com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException` . I'm editing my answer to include both sets of code.

Comment: I appended the failing code with comments indicating the lines that have been failing. I tested each while they were failing with the GS API Explorer using the spreadsheetID and the sheetID respectively, and the Explorer worked OK.

Comment: Well, the failing calls to `sheetsService.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId).execute()` was because of a typo in the spreadsheetId I introduced while debugging. The previous failure of `getSheetId()` was a real failure, that stopped failing because of something at the Google Cloud end as I described previously. I'm editing the posted code to remove the references to the typo error. Sorry for muddying the waters.

Comment: I have seen no further explanation. I accept that this problem was an intermittent failure of the Google client/server components.

Answer (score 0):

sheetId field of GridRange object is set to NULL when a corresponding named range was defined without a sheet part (i.e. just A1:B2 instead of Sheet1!A1:B2).

[A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation) chapter of Google API docs states that:

> A1:B2 refers to the first two cells in the top two rows of the first
>   visible sheet.

Comment: What does this isolated fact about GridRange have to do with the problem the Question asked about?